# Run puppeteer on vps ubuntu server without headless mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I want to login in instagram by puppeteer. I do this on my vps ubuntu server. But instagram know when I use headless mode and dont want to give access to login page. How can I launch puppeteer without handless mode?

Comment: https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.5.0&show=api-puppeteerlaunchoptions `headless` is a boolean value. Set it to false.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the headless property in launch() method's options argument to false:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false })
```